Complete set definiton in $ \mathbb{R}^n $
In my textbook the definiton of a complete set is given as such:
Set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is complete if every Cauchy sequence in $A$ converges.
It does not state, however, that the sequence must converge in A.
Is the definiton wrong or am I missing something?
How is the set (0, 1] not complete using given definiton?

Which textbook is that?

If you remove the requirement that it must converge in $A$ then every subset is complete which makes the definition absurd.

That should definitely be "converges in $A$". Otherwise, every subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ would be complete, as every Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb{R}^n$ converges in $\Bbb{R}^n$.

Yeah, that seems like big of a dodgy definition (if that is exactly what it says). Honestly, I'm used to seeing "completeness" being defined for a metric space, and in that case (with the word "space" instead of "subset") it's very strongly implied that we are considering a set in and of itself, and not as a subset of some ambient space.
I'd stick with the reading you're favoring, at least until I saw something else that contradicted it. If you have homework problems that hinge on which option is meant, you should ask your teacher/TA/grader to clarify.
